# Why do the heavy weapons all deal different damage?

Tags: dnd-5e

In the weapons table, the great weapons all deal different damage. My main question is primarily focussed on the Greatsword, and the Greataxe.

> - Greataxe - 1d12
> - Greatsword - 2d6

Now I understand the dynamics of the dice means different averages, but why is the damage different?

Comment: Are you looking for designer intent? Or just reasoning why based off of mechanics?

Comment: Just the mechanics. I realise designer intent is a bit far out of reach

Comment: Looks like you'll need to narrow this one down a bit further. I was thinking I'd try to give you an answer based off of the presence of certain game features that impact each weapon differently, but I suppose @SevenSidedDie is correct in that this is just tempting speculation and perhaps I'm falling for it

Comment: I remember [citation needed] a designer saying that in *AD&D*, for instance, a dagger deals 1d4 points of damage so folks would have a use for their d4s; likewise, I also remember [citation needed] a designer saying that in *3.5e* a greataxe deals 1d12 points of damage because the d12 was underused. In other words, it might be plausible to hunt down the design intent behind the current edition's choices.

Comment: @MarkRipley *In earlier editions of the game* that very well may've been the case. (I think at one point TSR bought the company from which it had been purchasing the dice included with the *D&D* box sets, for instance.) [citations needed] However, *for this question about the current edition*, I was merely making a comparison to dice commentary available for older editions in case Ben *wanted* to expand the question's mandate to cover design intent. The History of Dice in *D&D*, for example, is, I think, beyond this question's—much less these comments'!—scope! `:-)`

Comment: *"Just the mechanics. I realise designer intent is a bit far out of reach"* -- this is a bit confusing to me. Mechanics don't have a "why" independent of designer intent -- they just *are*; designer intent is the *entire* "why". Do you mean to ask what the practical difference is between 1d12 and 2d6 or something?

Comment: I can think of some nuance when you consider great weapon fighting style, the savage attacker feat, PCs with high crit chance (say, champion+advantage), all of which ties back to playstyle and weapon "style". However, those are answers to "How are these different" (in play) and not "why were these damage dice chosen".. I feel like this is *almost* an answerable question - the key to making your question not seem opinion-based is to *provide clear criteria for what the best answer will be* - we can do good subjective questions well here, but they can't be totally open-ended.

Comment: Just to be clear: yes, we actually prefer designer intent questions instead of “why is X part of the game the way it is” questions. It may be hard to *get* the designer intent, but that's OK — it might take a while to track down designer statements or not be answerable at all (if turns out that the statements don't exist), but if it *is* answerable, the answer will be excellent quality. Asking simply “why” ends up with very quick but highly speculative or opinion-based answers, followed by comments full of arguments — a result that SE is designed to avoid happening.